# I can't add any ppa in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, updates, ppa

I just installed Ubuntu on my machine and I just can't install any ppa, the command is running and never stops, I need to cancel the processor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

```
ubuntovini@ubuntovini-Aspire-A515-51G:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntudde-dev/stable
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 136, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 884, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 469, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 426, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 380, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 104, in get_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 96, in get_info_from_https
    data = func(lp_url=url, accept_json=accept_json, retry_delays=retry_delays)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 138, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1369, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1326, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1402, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 917, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I can sudo apt update

Comment: If you enter `python3 -V; python -V` what output do you get?  (two lines of output should be returned.. ie. have you changed the default python version??)

Comment: for python3 -V i have a output "Python 3.8.5"

Comment: I didn't understand what I'm going to do, I'm new to Linux

Comment: The traceback errors were created by the ^C you performed..  (so ignore all errors between the ^C until you see the "Keyboard Interrupt" which is the ^C..  (thanks @teward)

Comment: Try running `sudo apt install --reinstall software-properties-common` which should reinstall the `add-apt-repository`.

Comment: continues with the bug